# Customize the length of an input field

Tags: ember.js

How can I customize the length of a text input field? I use the following code and it results in a super long input field.

```
{{input type="text" value=searchText placeholder="Search..."}}
```

Comment: Try `size="..."` (or `style="width:...;"`)

Comment: On the similar line, if searchText is a property of your controller then you might want to do valueBinding="searchText", or the value is "searchText" then it should be value="searchText", definitely not without the quotes AKAIC

Comment: I've updated my answer, have a look if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Unspecified answered is somewhat correct, but it does not work correctly since the property you have to bind to should be called `maxlength` instead of `max-length`.

So you should rather do:

```
App.RestrictedTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['maxlength'],
  'maxlength': 10
});
```

and then use it like so:

```
{{view App.RestrictedTextField value=searchText placeholder="Search..."}}
```

Please see [here](http://jsbin.com/ikanir/1/edit) for a working jsbin.

Hope it helps.

**Update**
Following @David's comment this is equivalent to extending the `Ember.TextField`:

```
{{view Ember.TextField placeholder="Search..." maxlength=10 value="searchText"}}
```

and here an updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/abuvet/1/edit) showing the two approaches.

Comment: I am curious: is it equivalent to `{{view Ember.TextField placeholder="Search..." maxlength=10 value="searchText"}}` ?

Comment: @David yes it is, going to add it to my answer if you don't mind :)

Comment: I think we can edit an existing answer if there is any typo than adding another answer with the correction

Comment: @Unspecified well you are right, I could have correct your answer, but IMO we should put more effort when answering, don't we? and provide a **working** example? This is what I did.

Comment: I agree with the working example part, anyways no problems as long as the OP got the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how to define attributes in handlebars `{{input}}` helper but we can definitely accomplish this with the help of `attributeBindings`

```
App.RestrictedTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['maxlength'],
  'maxlength': 10
})

{{view App.RestrictedTextField value=searchText placeholder="Search..."}}
```